# "retailPrice" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: drjava

I keep getting the error message `"retailPrice cannot be resolved to a variable"`. I am getting it on several other lines as well but let's just start here.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class Billing

    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        computeBill(19.99);
        computeBill(19.99, 3);
        computeBill(19.99, 3, .20);
        computeBill(19.99, 3, .20, .10);
      }
      public static void computeBill(double book)
      {
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double retialPrice = (book * .085) + book;
        String total = (f.format(retailPrice));
        System.out.println("The photo book after tax is $" + total);
                           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled your variable name. see line:

```
    double retialPrice = (book * .085) + book;
```

You declare it misspelled as `retialPrice`, then in the next line you reference it spelled correctly as `retailPrice`.